# Python: Matplotlib avoid plotting gaps

Tags: python, matplotlib, datetime, time-series

I am currently generating the plot below:
[image: plot]

with this code:

```
ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(intra.to_pydatetime(), data)
plt.title('Intraday Net Spillover')
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

where `intra.to_pydatetime()` is a:
`<bound method DatetimeIndex.to_pydatetime of <class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2011-01-03 09:35:00, ..., 2011-01-07 16:00:00]
Length: 390, Freq: None, Timezone: None>`

So the dates go from `2011-01-03 09:35:00`, increments by 5 minutes until `16:00:00`, and then jumps to the next day, `2011-01-04 09:35:00` until `2011-01-04 16:00:00`, and so on.

How can I avoid plotting the gaps between 16:00:00 and 9:30:00 on the following day? I don't want to see these straight lines.

UPDATE:

I will try [this](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/dalejung/ts-charting/blob/master/notebooks/ohlc.ipynb) to see if it works.

Comment: I don't know if that's not too complicated, but I did that once by seperating the plotted series into multiple series and plotted each on its own, as I don't know how pandas should know what's a gap and what isn't.

Comment: Addendum: In one plot, but as seperate series, with same colour and linestyle, only giving a legend entry to the first.

Comment: For other users, although question is old, please review my answer and accept it if it worked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply set the two values defining the line you don't want to see as NaN (Not a Number). Matplotlib will hide the line between the two values automatically.

Check out this example :
http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/nan_test.html

Comment: A single `float('NaN')` is enough to create a gap.

Comment: this is just hide, but still showing the 'gap'

Comment: That is not true, the gaps are still there.

Answer (score 1):

Try to resample your dataframe.
For example :

```
df.plot()
```

gives me that result :
[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKKxX.png)

and now with resample:

```
df = df.resample('H').first().fillna(value=np.nan)
```

[plot after resample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFtVS.png)